# How to combine paramters in SSRS?

Tags: sql, reporting-services, ssrs-2008

I'm attempting to make a drop down list of choices for my report using 2 parameters. One is for when `jodrtg.fdescnum <> inmastx.fbin1` and the other is for when `fcomp_date<=GETDATE()-2`. There's supposed to be 3 options for the filters/parameters in the drop down list the first parameter, second parameter, and one for ALL RECORDS ignoring both of the parameters. I want only one of these options to be selected at once.I have the first parameter `jodrtg.fdescnum <> inmastx.fbin1` working in my dataset as well as the option to show ALL RECORDS. My problem is getting `fcomp_date<=GETDATE()-2` to work as an option in the same parameter drop down list.

```
     SELECT
    R,
    Stack,
        RTRIM(MoldNo) as MoldNo,
        Press,
        JobNo,
        Status,
        RelDate,
        StartByDate,
        Priority,
        RTRIM(WH) as WH,
        MoldLoc,
        foperno,
        flschedule,
        RTRIM(WC) as WC,
        fcomp_date,
        flastlab,
        RTRIM(MoldDesc) as MoldDesc,
        Cavitation,
        MoldDims,
        Type,
        fddDueDate,
        fDueDate,
        foperqty,
        fnqty_comp,
        fnqty_togo,
        fnqty_move
    FROM
    (
    SELECT
        jodbom.fbompart as MoldNo, 
        jodrtg.fdescnum AS Press,
        jomast.fjobno as JobNo,
          jomast.fstatus as Status,
        jomast.frel_dt as RelDate,
          jomast.ftduedate as StartByDate,
        jomast.fschdprior as Priority,
        inmastx.flocate1 AS WH,
        inmastx.fbin1 AS MoldLoc,
        jodrtg.foperno as foperno,
        jodrtg.flschedule as flschedule,
        jodrtg.fpro_id as WC,
        jodrtg.fcomp_date as fcomp_date,
        jomast.flastlab as flastlab ,
        inmastx.fdescript AS MoldDesc,
          inmastx.fcusrchr2 AS Cavitation,
        inmastx.fcusrchr3 AS MoldDims,
        jomast.ftype as Type,
        jomast.fddue_date as fddDueDate,
        sorels.fduedate as fDueDate,
        jodrtg.foperqty as foperqty,
        jodrtg.fnqty_comp as fnqty_comp ,
        jodrtg.fnqty_togo as fnqty_togo,
        jodrtg.fnqty_move as fnqty_move,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY jodbom.fbompart ORDER BY jomast.frel_dt,jomast.fschdprior,jomast.fjobno) R,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY jodrtg.fdescnum ORDER BY jodrtg.fdescnum,jomast.frel_dt,jomast.fschdprior,jomast.fjobno) Stack

        FROM jodbom 
        INNER JOIN jomast ON jodbom.fjobno =  jomast.fjobno
        INNER JOIN jodrtg ON jomast.fjobno = jodrtg.fjobno 
        INNER JOIN inmastx ON jodbom.fbompart = inmastx.fpartno
        LEFT JOIN sorels ON jomast.fsono+jomast.fkey = sorels.fsono+sorels.finumber+sorels.frelease 
        WHERE Left(jomast.fstatus,1) <> 'C' AND jomast.flisapl = 1 AND jodbom.fltooling = 1 AND jodrtg.fpro_id <> '09' AND flschedule=1 

and (jodrtg.fdescnum <> inmastx.fbin1
    OR @Setup is null)



    ) Q
    WHERE  R = 1
```

Comment: This is not a minimal question, and without sample data or a demo, it might be hard for others to help you.

Comment: This is generally a bad idea.  You're brutalising the query planner.  But what you're asking for is simply `(@param IS NULL) OR (<condition1> AND @param = 1) OR (<condition2> AND @param = 2)`

Comment: @David You don't use GETDATE() in SSRS like you have done in your question. `fcomp_date<=GETDATE()-2`. In SSRS you would use Now(). Unless I have misunderstood and that is what you use in your query and not in the ssrs parameter expression.

Comment: `fcomp_date<=GETDATE()-2` IF this is meant to be minusing 2 days from GETDATE() you should use the dateadd() function. Like this `DATEADD(dd, -2, GETDATE())`

Comment: @MatBailie I'm trying to use just one parameter to meet the 3 conditions. I want to keep it a down to one dropdown list with the 3 conditions as Specified Values.

Comment: @David - My example still holds.  It uses only one parameter to "invoke" one of three possible conditions.  If the param is `NULL` you get all rows, if it's `1` you filter by <condition1>, whatever you want that to be, if it's `2` you filter by <condition2>, whatever you want that to be.  And all the time, you will brutalise the optimiser / query planner; because you will generate ***one*** execution plan that tries to satisfy all three possibilities : http://www.sommarskog.se/dyn-search.html

Comment: @MatBailie I see what you're saying. I'll give the link a read. Do you think I'd be better off having 3 separate parameters?

Comment: Three separate queries.  Possibly make the body of the query a view or something, and then the three queries only vary in the WHERE clause used.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answered with help from the comments.

`(
(jodrtg.fcomp_date  <= DATEADD(dd,-2,GETDATE())
And @Setup=1)
Or
(@Setup is null)
Or
(jodrtg.fdescnum <> inmastx.fbin1 
AND @Setup =2)
 )`